# Getting file in JAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, embedded-resource

I'm converting a java project to a JAR but when I convert it, some files that I make calls to no longer exist.

For example, in my playSound method (while plays music), I get the file that I want like this:

```
public void playSound(String fileName) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then, I call the method like this:

```
playSound("src/main/java/calgaryFlamesTracker/music/Fall.wav");
```

This works fine in intelliJ but when I do the same thing through the JAR, it says the file does not exist. I read something about use getClass().getResource() but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: You read correctly, although it's easier to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`. The absolute resource path is `/calgaryFlamesTracker/music/Fall.wav`.

Comment: @RobSpoor I'm doing that and it is returning null. Where do I call the getClass().getResourceAsStream(...) part? In place of the filename correct?

Comment: @AndrewThonpson I have rarely seen a less relevant 'duplicate'. VTR.

Comment: @EdvinSinko a null return means the resource cannot be found. Moving it to the resources folder probably solved that. Maven seems to not process resources from the java folder.